# Edições no código ou nas mensagens de erro das perguntas

Tags: debate, edição, edições-sugeridas

Por vezes, vejo edições que:

- São realizadas em perguntas.
- Não são realizadas pelo autor da pergunta.
- Reformatam, re-indentam ou corrigem problemas no código postado ou na mensagem de erro.
- Não são apenas correções de formatação. São de fato alterações no código-fonte ou nas mensagens de erro.

Acredito que esse tipo de edição é danosa, mesmo que seja para arrumar a endentação de um código. O código e as mensagens de erro na pergunta devem ser **expressão da verdade**. Ou seja, expressam o problema real do autor da pergunta tal como ele o vê em seu ambiente de desenvolvimento.

Entretanto, quando alguma outra pessoa edita isso, vários problemas podem ocorrer:

- O problema pode não mais ser reproduzível, ao menos não da forma como o autor da pergunta alega que é.
- A mensagem de erro apresentada pode não mais coincidir com aquela que o código produz.
- Números de linhas podem não mais coincidir.
- O código da pergunta simplesmente deixa de ser aquele que apresenta o problema do autor da pergunta. Ou seja, deixa de ser **expressão da verdade**.

Já vi inúmeras edições sugeridas (e aprovadas) nesse sentido e mesmo edições feitas por quem já tem reputação suficiente para não entrar na fila de aprovação.

Esse tipo de edição é permitido? Se sim, por quê? Eu pessoalmente quando vejo uma dessas na fila de edição rejeito, mas mesmo assim ela é aprovada por outros revisores.

Note que isso só se aplica às perguntas. Edições desse tipo em respostas (a menos que tenham outros tipos de problemas) considero bem-vindas.

Comment: Também tenho visto isso, mas tem gente que aprova nas filas, não há muito o que se fazer. Por isso passo nas filas raramente.

Comment: Pior é que se você avisa o editor, você fica como o "usuário metido a moderador chato" ainda.

Answer (score 9):

Em especial, com [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/250353/132) ocorreu um problema exatamente por conta de editar-se o código-fonte da pergunta para se corrigir a identação.

O código estava assim:

```c
 //captura os elementos
 for(i=0;i<3;i++)
 for(j=0;j<3;j++){
 printf("Elemento[%d][%d]= ",i,j);
 tecla[0] = getche();
 scanf("%c",&m[i][j]);
 }
 printf("\n::: Valores Originais :::\n");
 for(i=0;i<3;i++){
 for(j=0;j<3;j++)
 printf("%c ",m[i][j]);
 tecla[0] = getche();
 printf("\n");
 }
```

Um outro usuário a reidentou e colocou assim:

```
 //captura os elementos
 for(i=0;i<3;i++)
     for(j=0;j<3;j++){
         printf("Elemento[%d][%d]= ",i,j);
         tecla[0] = getche();
         scanf("%c",&m[i][j]);
     } 

 //EXIBIR VALORES ORIGINAIS
 printf("\n::: Valores Originais :::\n");
 for(i=0;i<3;i++){
     for(j=0;j<3;j++)
         printf("%c ",m[i][j]);
         tecla[0] = getche();
         printf("\n");
     }
```

Observe acima que alguns laços `for` tem o `{` enquanto outros não. Em especial, a linha `tecla[0] = getche();` próxima ao final não está dentro do `for` externo, mas foi identada como se estivesse.

Elaborei uma resposta onde eu ressaltava o erro de identação. Ocorre que esse erro foi introduzido na pergunta por uma pessoa que não a autora da pergunta!

Em vista dessa confusão, reverti as mudanças na identação da pergunta e alterei minha resposta.

No dia seguinte, um outro usuário editou a pergunta e reintroduziu o problema na identação. A edição dele entrou na fila de edições sugeridas, mas foi aprovada mesmo assim. A própria autora da pergunta reverteu a edição.

Esse caso evidencia que editar o código da pergunta para corrigir-se erros, mesmo que seja identação, é algo que pode ser perigoso, um perigo muitas vezes negligenciado por quem faz a edição. **Por vezes, reindentar-se o código é parte da solução do problema, e portanto é algo que deveria estar na resposta, e não na pergunta.**

Infelizmente, essa não é a primeira vez que vejo algo assim acontecer. Inclusive, uma das motivações que tive quando criei essa pergunta aqui no meta foi exatamente essa.

Comment: A fila de edições virou bagunça. Tem usuário aprovando sem ler, provavelmente atrás de medalha. Eu mesmo já fiz um teste numa resposta minha, onde inseri um erro proposital que alterava o resultado do meu código, alguém viu e editou, alterando meu código, e ninguem na fila se atentou a ler e rejeitar. Muito estão simplesmente clicando em "aprovar", e são bem ativos na fila, ai fica dificil até pra gente rejeitar. Já alertei alguns revisores mas nem todos dão a minima pros avisos.

Comment: @Articuno eu já tive essa discussão como o pessoal do SOpt, a cerca de um ano atrás, e pelo que entendi continua valendo "vai do bom senso das pessoas que analisam". Eu pessoalmente não concordo em essas medalhas justamente por causa disso.

Answer (score 5):

Não vejo problema em editar indentação. Em geral isso ajuda tanto o autor da pergunta quanto os demais usuários a encontrar o erro.

Com relação a alteração de linhas, é raro nós termos:

- arquivo de código completo, para que possamos verificar o número de cada linha - e se tivéssemos os arquivos completos, provavelmente os exemplos não seriam mínimos;
- indicação do autor da pergunta sobre a linha exata que causa o problema. Quando nós temos essa indicação, o número da linha na mensagem de erro pode ser irrelevante.

Tirando esses dois pontos, eu concordo com a pergunta.

Comment: Com exceção do Python, acredito que não tenha problema alterar a indentação :P