# Porque essa edição foi aprovada?

Tags: debate, edição

Estou tentando entender porque está [edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/200389/4) foi [aprovada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/147315), sendo que a justificativa dada para essa edição foi:

> Mascara estava incorreta, forçando somente os números 0

A pergunta tem um link para o [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/znuph72f/40/) e como podem notar, a mascara que é informada lá é justamente  `000.000.000-000` e funciona perfeitamente, pelo menos eu não tive nenhum problema.

Comment: Mais conhecido como "aprovar sem ler" :D

Comment: Eu acho até que sste pode ser caso da pessoasachar que é coisa boa.

Comment: Detalhe curioso é que o editor já havia respondido com a solução que ele alterou na resposta, ou seja, edição completamente desnecessária.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

De fato isto foi um erro, a pessoa que editou está mudando a pergunta em uma forma que pode não ser o que a pessoa quer. Pior, pode ser que tenha resolvido o problema. Pior ainda, pode ter causado outro problema. A única edição código é o que coloca indentação inicial geral para que o texto seja mostrado como código. Não se deve sequer indentar o código para ficar mais alinhado, mais "bonito" já que isto pode mudar a intenção da pergunta.

As pessoas que aprovaram conformaram o erro.

Tem algo especificamente sobre isto já postado aqui, mas não achei, algum Victor vai achar :P

Este é um caso que vale a reversão (faça as honras) e talvez uma melhoria em seguida que não cause problemas (mesmo que não cause um problema, o potencial já é suficiente, o código é aquele que o AP postou). Tem várias melhorias possíveis ali.

Tomara que os aprovadores vejam isto.

Comment: Eu reverti, mas que isso vem acontecendo com uma certa frequencia, vem. Eu só não to mais chiando muito porque cada vez que reclamo, um deles começa a perseguir com negativos aleatórios, vasculhando respostas e perguntas antigas minhas. É melhor ficar calado e deixar o erro acontecer, é isso que to fazendo agora.

Comment: Lendo [essa](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6300/edi%C3%A7%C3%B5es-no-c%C3%B3digo-ou-nas-mensagens-de-erro-das-perguntas) resposta do Victor, entendo que em alguns caso a identação possa ser parte da solução do problema, talvez em códigos Python ou C, mas em outros pode melhorar a leitura e consequentemente o entendimento do problema sem interferir no erro ou intenção do autor, como em alguns trechos Javascript. *Não se deve sequer indentar o código para ficar mais alinhado* vale como regra sempre ou pode depender da tag e/ou do impacto?

Comment: @LucasCosta Sempre é bom usar algum contexto e não seguir cegamente nada. Eu acho perigoso arrumar essas coisas porque pode mudar a intenção sem querer apesar de deixar mais legível. Entenda q é diferente dar uma tabulada inicial igual em tudo para que o código fique com a marcação de código (https://help.github.com/articles/creating-and-highlighting-code-blocks/), é difícil errar aí, mas uma indentada seletiva eu acho arriscado.