# Qual o segredo para uma boa edição?

Tags: debate, edição

Eu sou meio novato por aqui (frequento o SO<sup>EN</sup> há muitos anos como "consumidor de respostas", mas só há um ano e pouco como usuário cadastrado, quando precisei fazer minha primeira pergunta, e só depois disso descobri o SO<sup>PT</sup>), então ainda estou aprendendo as regras e *macetes* da comunidade. E, desde que ganhei a permissão para editar perguntas e respostas, tenho uma certa dúvida sobre como fazer uma boa edição, que seja aprovada pelo resto da comunidade.

Eu sou um pouco perfeccionista e muitas vezes quando vejo qualquer erro ortográfico, como acentos ou pontuação faltando, tenho uma tendência a querer arrumar (e vi que isso acontece com outros usuários também, inclusive moderadores com "TOC", hehe). E desde o começo eu fui "motivado" pelo site a fazer essas pequenas correções, ortográficas ou gramaticais, nas mensagens:

> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/editing
>
> É esperado que as edições sejam substanciais e que deixem a publicação melhor do que foi encontrada. Os motivos mais comuns para fazer edições são:
>
> - **Corrigir erros de gramática e ortografia**
> - Esclarecer o significado da publicação (sem alterar esse significado)
> - Incluir outras informações encontradas apenas nos comentários, de modo que todas as informações relevantes para a publicação estejam contidas em um único lugar
> - Corrigir erros menores ou adicionar atualizações com o tempo
> - Adicionar hyperlinks ou recursos relacionados

Mas, também logo no começo descobri que, embora o site me motivasse a fazer tais correções, a **comunidade** me desmotivava a fazer essas correções "simples", porque a maioria das correções que fiz somente corrigindo ortografia e gramática foram rejeitadas (e no começo eu nem sabia que edição dava pontos, comecei simplesmente para arrumar os textos mesmo).

Então, comecei a me segurar para editar os textos apenas quando houvesse algo mais. Mas, mesmo assim de vez em quando tenho edições rejeitadas. Então, fico na dúvida de como proceder, porque o site diz uma coisa, mas a comunidade diz outra.

Ontem por exemplo, eu fiz a seguinte edição:

> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/191370

Que, sim, corrige alguns erros ortográficos não muito gritantes, e melhora a formatação de forma que não agrega muita coisa, **mas**, também corrige essa parte do texto `o pTest[1].Player.Name (também vira o Grim)`, que é um comentário mas está dentro do bloco de amostra de código, como se fosse parte do código. Então, ao meu ver era uma edição relevante, mas, foi rejeitada.

E é engraçado porque ontem mesmo eu tive algumas edições aprovadas que depois eram editadas novamente simplesmente para arrumar a quantidade de espaços na identação do código (de 4 espaços para 2), o que me parece uma edição menos relevante ainda.

Curiosamente, um dos revisores que rejeitou a minha edição tem invariavelmente rejeitado **todas** as minhas edições, não sei por qual motivo (ele nunca aceitou nenhuma edição minha, que eu me lembre, mesmo as que são aprovadas por outros dois usuários), e justamente esse mesmo usuário que rejeitou minha edição tinha feito a edição anterior nessa pergunta.

Também curiosamente, a minha resposta a essa mesma pergunta (que me parece correta e válida: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/336482/86952) foi negativada ao mesmo tempo em que minha edição foi rejeitada. Mas isso é apenas um "desabafo em voz alta", não tem relação com a dúvida principal.

Então, fica a pergunta, qual é de fato o critério para uma boa edição, que seja aceita pela comunidade?

Comment: A primeira edição que você linkou na pergunta eu teria aceite e é uma edição que me parece util, mas tenha atenção a edições de código que indentam o código, pois não as deve fazer. [Leia essa pergunta relacionada com esse tema](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6300/edi%C3%A7%C3%B5es-no-c%C3%B3digo-ou-nas-mensagens-de-erro-das-perguntas). Essas indentações são certamente motivos de algumas das suas rejeições.

Comment: @Isac, na verdade essas edições que comentei, que apenas arrumavam a identação do código, foram feitas por outro usuário, que inclusive tem reputação suficiente para editar diretamente. Mas, confesso que vez ou outra eu faço alguma edição no código, embora eu costume tomar muito cuidado e alterar só aquilo que tenho certeza que não fará diferença em termos de execução, mas que pode melhorar a legibilidade, como esse caso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/191433, e esse: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/191592 (mas imagino que vocês desaprovariam ambos!).

Comment: Também sei que algumas linguaguens são sensíveis à identação, como Python por exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/284988/86952. Em geral eu costumo não mexer no código, mas, não mexerei mais nada no código então, a não ser para formatar melhor. Obrigado pelas dicas!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Um dos problemas que eu vejo é que a comunidade não gosta de que as edições sejam feitas para ganhar os 2 pontinhos. Tanto que as pessoas já não ligam mais quando suas edições não precisam ser aprovadas e não ganha mais os pontos.

Uma sugestão que dou é tentar seguir os padrões e evitar corrigir qualquer erro bobo neste início. Veja [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/101). Também tente consertar todos os erros, isto ajuda passar a ideia que você se dedicou. Cuidado para não mudar a intenção, mudar o código, incluindo a formatação, porque o erro pode estar lá e você pode tirá-lo, ou colocar um novo. Eu só mexo no código para dar a tabulação necessária pelo *markdown*.

Alguns usuários são meio chatos demais com essas edições mesmo :) Poderiam aceitar coisas que ajudam de verdade. E tem usuários que não entende bem como revisar a fila. Muitas vezes porque [agiram mal com ela e aí aprendeu errado](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ePmIP8qS3A0).

Se você acha que sistematicamente tem edições boas rejeitas por algum usuário específico, tenta falar calma e educadamente com ela para ver o que está fazendo de errado, quem sabe ela fale aqui para você.

Não desanime, sei que pode ser frustrante, mas com algum esforço obterá bons resultados. Mostrar que está com boas intenções aqui pode ajudar.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas, Maniero. O guia no link que você passou foi muito útil, esclareceu várias coisas. Deveria estar linkado na ajuda de edição do site! Seria muito útil. Por exemplo, eu estava fazendo isso de vez em quando: *Não use  `` (código-inline) para dar ênfase ou para formatar siglas ou nomes próprios. A formatação de código deve ser reservada somente para código e assemelhados.*, não farei mais.

Comment: Realmente às vezes desanima um pouco... tem vezes que dedico algumas horas do meu dia pra ficar arrumando textos, para depois serem rejeitadas, dá vontade de deixar para lá mesmo. Eu faço as correções porque gosto de ver "a casa arrumada" (já que agora faço parte da comunidade), mas, é claro que faço pelos pontos também, afinal é só com mais pontos na reputação que coseguimos acesso a mais privilégios, que nos permitem participar cada vez mais. E, acho justo receber 2 pontinhos por gastar meu tempo cuidando do texto dos outros, visando um bem geral da comunidade, mas essa é só minha opinião!

Comment: Uma última dúvida: Quando você sugere que eu converse calma e educamente com o usuário que eu comentei, qual seria a forma mais correta e indicada para fazer isso? Eu vi em algum post uma sugestão para publicar um comentário na mensagem editada, com *@NomeDoUsuário*, mas, acho que dessa forma uma conversa que deveria ser "privada" acaba ficando pública demais, e também acaba inserindo um comentário que não tem nada a ver com a pergunta. Tem algum outro canal melhor para fazer isso?

Comment: Pode fazer isto e apagar os comentários depois e pedir para a pessoa fazer o mesmo ou sinalizar para moderadores o fazerem, mas se for algo longo seria melhor abrir uma sala de chat que pode até ser privada, mas sem um *link* de acesso raramente alguém entrará e ver. Se qualquer forma se a conversa é amistosa, não vejo necessidade que seja privado. Só cuidado para não criar algum problema, só tente ver o que pode melhorar.