# Posso ser bloqueado por várias edições reprovadas?

Tags: suporte, edições-sugeridas

Eu não posso fazer perguntas no SOpt-br. Acostumei já.
Já que o que eu posso fazer é votar e editar tags, perguntas e respostas, tem como eu ter a minha conta bloqueada se eu tiver um certo número de edições reprovadas?

Comment: Sobre o bloqueio de fazer perguntas (ou respostas): [Como remover o aviso "Você atingiu o limite de questões"?](/q/6474/3635) e [Fui bloqueado de postar e responder! O que fazer?](/q/7621/3635).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *tem como eu ter a minha conta bloqueada se eu tiver um certo número de edições reprovadas?*

Sim. De acordo com a [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/editing):

> *qualquer usuário que enviar muitas edições rejeitadas terá a sugestão de outras edições vetada por 7 dias.*

[Aqui](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92337/401803) tem uma fórmula que determina quanto é esse "muitas". Mas como a resposta é de 2011, pode ser que já tenha mudado. De qualquer forma, o ideal é sempre seguir as orientações da Central de Ajuda (no link já indicado acima), assim você não precisa se preocupar com fórmula nenhuma. [Isso aqui](/a/7388/112052) também pode ajudar a melhorar suas sugestões de edição.

Por fim, [esta resposta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355727) também cita que, além da suspensão automática de 7 dias, também há a possibilidade de suspensão manual por parte da moderação, conforme detalhado [em outra resposta](/a/8869/112052).

Answer (score 3):

Sim, é possível ser bloqueado de fazer isso também. A solução é melhorar as ações que faz, inclusive porque elas revertem bloqueios mais rapidamente. Então é interessante ver o padrão que faz algo ser ruim e o que faz ser bom, e procurar fazer só dentro do padrão bom.

Answer (score 3):

Complementando as respostas já dadas:

Sugestões de edição "caça-níquel" em série, mesmo que aceitas, também podem levar a suspensão desta atividade em específico por certos períodos.

Infelizmente esse é um expediente que volta e meia ocorre no site, quando a busca por reputação se torna maior do que o interesse em realmente agregar.

Tem casos de usuários que depois do bloqueio (atenção, não estou falando do caso do autor da pergunta aqui especificamente) entram num "streak" de edições que acaba mais atrapalhando do que ajudando (até por um desvio de finalidade), ocupando "largura de banda" da comunidade aumentando as filas e necessidade de análise desnecessariamente, tirando o foco das coisas mais relevantes.

Nesses casos o critério é a análise de conjunto, não basta ter "edições aceitas" - especialmente quando já teve uma rejeição e foi override do autor, ou a pessoa insiste em tentar editar os mesmos posts.

Outra característica que chama atenção nesses casos é que tem séries de edições, mas com contribuições mínimas (meramente adicionando detalhes de formatação não tão importantes em posts já fechados, e outras características que indicam que o foco é a pontuação e não a qualidade do site).

Que fique claro que o simples fato de alguém fazer em série não é problema nenhum, muito pelo contrário. Os critérios são bem mais detalhados - tem várias outras coisas analisadas nesses casos, seja por ferramentas específicas e avaliação postagem por postagem, o importante é que todas avaliam o intuito geral e histórico - e tem todo um cuidado na análise.

A dica é, se é pra editar, maximizar a utilidade:

> [Qual o segredo para uma boa edição?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7387/70)